# Regex Australian phone number

Tags: javascript, regex

I've been trying to create a regex to map parts of Australian phone numbers.

Until now I got it working with the following

`\s*(\+61|61|061)?\s*[^\d\(]?\s*(\(?([0-8][2-8]{0,1})\)?\s*[\D]?\s*([0-9]{4})\s*[\D]?\s*([0-9]{4}))(?:\D{0,16}(\d{0,8}))?`

Here's a link to test it:

https://regex101.com/r/jN2fU8/13

PS: The REGEX is also working for:

+610491570156 , +61 04 9157 0156 , +614 9157 0156, others

However I'd like add also the possibility of having the phone-number like this:

+61 491 570 156

And have it mapping my number the same way as the other one (the groups)

Does anyone have an idea of how I should change to accomplish that?

Comment: Some phone numbers have 12 digits while others have 11. Does Australian phone numbers vary in digit count?

Comment: It helps if you provide a long list of test examples that need to match.

Comment: Or at least a few that have all the same number of digits

Comment: I think I'd run a cleanup first, before trying to match the groups. That means removing whitespaces, removing unnecessary zeros, etc, to try to make it uniform first. Then try matching the groups.

Comment: Hi @zer00ne .. some of them have 12 because the area code can be written with 0 (zero) in front of the number.

Comment: @linden2015 removing the spaces must be the best solution.. I don't even know why I didn't think about it lol Thank you!

Comment: Don't do this...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could replace all the non digits to normalize the input and then run the regexp

```js
var phoneNumber = '+061 04 9157 0156'
var text = phoneNumber.replace(/[^\d]/g,'');

console.log(text);//061491570156
    
var regex = /0?(61)0?(\d{1,2})(\d{4})(\d{4})/g;
    
var matcher = regex.exec(text);
    
console.log(phoneNumber)//+061 04 9157 0156
console.log(matcher[0])//061491570156
console.log(matcher[1])//61
console.log(matcher[2])//4
console.log(matcher[3])//9157
console.log(matcher[4])//0156
```

Comment: This is a useful technique in general, but it doesn't change the fact the OP should not be writing the 89th version of a regexp for Australian phone numbers, which will end up being broken in new and special ways.

Answer (score 5):

Parsing phone numbers in general is a mess. I would suggest using a library like [libphonenumber-js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/libphonenumber-js).

```js
const formatted = new libphonenumber.asYouType().input( '+61 491570156' );
console.log( formatted );
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/libphonenumber-js/0.4.27/libphonenumber-js.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Sorry. I can't use any library. I should do that with regex, but thanks for the solution.

Comment: @HugoS.Mendes If not using a library is a requirement, then you should write that in the question, preferably with an explanation of why you can't or don't want to.